# QML: How to fill a Rectangle with a Layout

Tags: qt, layout, qml

I have page with a rectangle in the middle and I want to fill the rectangle with a Layout. This is the basic hierarchy I want to achieve:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {   
    Rectangle {        
        width: parent.width/3
        height: parent.height/3
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        ColumnLayout {                
            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent/4
                color: "red"
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent/4 
                color: "blue"
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that defining ColumnLayout in the Rectangle ends up with error (Qt Creator underscore the word). What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you imported `QtQuick.Layouts x`? Do you need the `Layouts` or would you be ok, with just using anchors for positioning?

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks, that's it.

Comment: Your `Layout` is useless in the example above. You should set size, probably `anchors.fill: parent`. Also setting size for layout's element should be set using Layout attached properties like `Layout.preferredWidth`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are doing

```
height: parent/4
```

that should be

```
height: parent.height/4
```

and try to use Item for layout instead of Rectangle have a look

```
Item {
    width: 900
    height: 900

    Item {
        width:  parent.width/3
        height: parent.height/3
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height/4
                color: "red"
            }

            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height/4
                color: "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```